# matchAll() not functioning as documented: Regex testing site says regex works, nodejs says its undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, capture-group

https://regex101.com/r/SoxbQ0/1

This shows the exact regex capturing the groups.

but put it in js and this shows it not capturing the groups:

https://jsfiddle.net/nbpqdu5r/3/

```
let apiresponse = "│            test-scripts │                  6 │                  0 │"

let matching = new RegExp('(?:\│\s+test-scripts\s+\│\s+)([0-9]+)(?:\s+\│\s+)([0-9]+)(?:\s+\│)$','gm');

let testScriptResults = apiresponse.matchAll(matching)

console.log(testScriptResults)
```

What is the discrepancy?

Comment: Use a regex literal, otherwise you have to escape backslashes. `new RegExp('\s').toString()` is a minimal reproducible example -- it's a string problem, not a `matchAll` problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried 

let matching = new RegExp('(?:\│\s+test-scripts\s+\│\s+)([0-9]+)(?:\s+\│\s+)([0-9]+)(?:\s+\│)$','gm').toString();

Which produced the same result.

Going to research more into what a regex literal is.